# Popup doesn't work with ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, ngroute

In a web application, after the login, the user see a page in which there are a button for open a css popup. It works, but when I put the project in phonegap and I use ngRoute the popup doesn't work, because it always return in login page.

The first time that the user logs, he will be found all disabled except for a button that opens a popup. When he closes the popup, he can continue browsing. For this I save in the cookie popup status.

This is the popup in the home-page:

```
<div class="icon-wrapper"> 
    <a href="#popup" ng-click="open();"><img  ng-src="img.png" /></a> 
</div> 
<!-- Popup -->
<div class="overlay" id="popup" ng-class="$storage.hide">
    <p>Test</p>
<button ng-click="close();">Close popup</button>
```

Angular code of the home-page:

```
var app = angular.module('Home', ['ngStorage']);

app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, $http, $localStorage){ 

$scope.hide = "hide";      

$scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({ 
    hide: $scope.hide   
});


$scope.close = function () {
  window.location = '#';  
};

$scope.open = function () {
  $scope.$storage.hide = "show";  
};

}); // End controller
```

CSS

```
.hide { display: none;}
.show { display: block; }
```

JS File of the index page (in which there is the ng-view):

```
angular.module('Authentication', []);
angular.module('Home', []);

angular.module('BasicHttpAuthExample', [
'Authentication',
'Home',
'ngRoute',
'ngCookies',
'ngStorage'
])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider
    .when('/login', {
        controller: 'LoginController',
        templateUrl: 'js/modules/authentication/views/login.html',
        hideMenus: true
    })

    .when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'js/modules/home/views/home.html'
    })

    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}])
```

Actually, when I try to open the popup I turn back in login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="#popup" ng-click="open();"><img  ng-src="img.png" /></a>
```

Will route you to e.g. localhost:9000/#popup.
This route isn't delcared in your routeProvider, so he will jump to the login.
To jump to your home-site, do it like:

```
<a href="#/" ng-click="open();"><img  ng-src="img.png" /></a>
```